# Pjax/Ajax fragment returning width/offsetWidth of 0 on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, requirejs, pjax

Running into a difficult bug with Pjax fragments on the following site:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/65752410/map.html

Currently, clicking on the "schedule" and "map" links in the nav will load page fragments via Pjax along with some conditional javascript, courtesy of requirejs.

On the "map" page, the first page load will calculate the width of each element with a class of `.side-panel` correctly. However, subsequent loads will return a width of 0, despite the fact that the selected element is present in the DOM when the width is queried.

To reproduce the bug:

1. wait until the map loads
2. click the "schedule" link to load the schedule page
3. click the "map" link to load the map page. The width of each `.side_panel` will be logged as 0.

If you keep the console open during this test, you'll see that the proper width is logged on page load, the schedule page is dynamically loaded in the second step, and the map page is then loaded with the `.side_panel` elements in the DOM, but returning a width of 0.

Comment: f you look at the console, the panel div doesn't have an offsetParent, which means it's not yet been inserted into the DOM, which would mean that the width will be 0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the console, the panel div doesn't have an `offsetParent`, which means it's not yet been inserted into the DOM, which would mean that the width will be 0.

Comment: You are 100% right. It had to do with caching the jQuery object—the reference was for an old set of elements, which had since been removed from the DOM. Thank you!